# php calling a function through with autoloader

Tags: php, oop

These are my classes

```
class DB{

    // returns the instance as it should - all system works well

    public function create(){
      // creates a row in the db....    
    }
```

}

```
class User{
    // does all it does....
}
```

I have an autoloader that loads the classes and the system works well

```
$user = new User();
$user->create(....)
```

I want to use the method create from the DB while instantiating User class, how can I do so?

**the thing that I want to prevent** is not having to need to create a function "update" in every class which needs to be updated

For example:

Class user - update "users table"
class kids - update "kids table"

instead

```
// from DB class
update($table_name, $field)
```

Comment: Tried a coule of things and got undefined method $user->create, as i tried to move it to DB class.

As i understand $user = new User has access to all other classes with the autoloader so when i try to call a function from DB it should come up...probably thats what im missing to understand

Answer (score 1):

The autoloader is responsible for finding the and including the files that contain the class definitions so you don't have to explicitly call `include 'db.php';` etc. , but it isn't going to be able to do what you're trying to do here.

If the `create()` method is defined in the `DB` class, there's no reason for it to be accessible through an instance of a different class like `User`, and unless you specifically do something to allow it, the autoloader won't help with that.

The only way for you to access the `DB::create()` method from an instance of `User` is for `User` to extend `DB`.

```
class User extends DB { ...
```

This means that all `User` objects will also be instances of `DB` and have access to *all* of the public and protected methods of `DB`, not just `create()`.

It looks like this might be what you want. If that's the case, it would be helpful for you to read up on [Object Inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php#language.oop5.inheritance).